# Why does my output not match the expected output and how can I make it match?

Tags: java, arraylist

here is a dictionary program.

Code Provided

```
import java.util.*;

public enum Dictionary {

    DistinctADJECTIVEONE("Distinct","adjective","Familiar. Worked in Java."),
    DistinctADJECTIVETWO("Distinct","adjective","Unique. No duplicates. Clearly different or of a different kind."),
    DistinctADVERB("Distinct","adverb","Uniquely. Written 'distinctly.'"),
    DistinctNOUNONE("Distinct","noun","A keyword in this assignment."),
    DistinctNOUNTWO("Distinct","noun","A keyword in this assignment."),
    DistinctNOUNTHREE("Distinct","noun","A keyword in this assignment."),
    DistinctNOUNFOUR("Distinct","noun","An advanced search option."),
    DistinctNOUNFIVE("Distinct","noun","Distinct is a parameter in this assignment.");

    private final String generalNote = "Dictionary";
    private String keyword;
    private String partOfSpeech;
    private String definition;

    private Dictionary(String keyword, String partOfSpeech, String definition) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
        this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return this.keyword.toUpperCase();
    }


    public String definition(){
        return this.definition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.keyword + " [" + this.partOfSpeech + "] : " + this.definition;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("! Loading data...");

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Dictionary>> hmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Dictionary>>();

        for (Dictionary dict : Dictionary.values()) {

            String keyword = dict.getKeyword();
            ArrayList<Dictionary> list = (hmap.containsKey(keyword)) ? hmap.get(keyword) : new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
            list.add(dict);
            hmap.put(keyword, list);
        }

        System.out.println("! Loading Complete...");

        Boolean quite = true;
        int counter = 7;

        do {
            counter++;
            System.out.print("[" + counter + "] Search: ");
            String userinput = input.nextLine();
            String[] splited = userinput.split(" ");

            String word = null;
            Boolean requestDistinct = false;

            if (splited.length > 0) {
                word = splited[0];
            }

            if (splited.length > 1 && splited[1]!= null) {
                if (splited[1].equalsIgnoreCase("distinct")) {
                    requestDistinct = true;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("   |");
                    System.out.println("    <The entered 2nd parameter " + userinput + " is NOT 'distinct'.>\n" +
                            "   <The 2nd parameter should be a part of speech or 'distinct'.>");
                    System.out.println("   |");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if(!userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("!q")) {
                System.out.println("   |");

                ArrayList<Dictionary> result = hmap.get(word.toUpperCase());
                ArrayList<Dictionary> secondResult = (requestDistinct) ? returnDictionaryWithDistinctDefinition(result) : result;

                if (secondResult != null && secondResult.size()>0) {
                    for(Dictionary key : secondResult) {
                        System.out.print("    " + key + "\n");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("   |");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n----Thank You---");
                quite = false;
            }
            requestDistinct = false;
        } while(quite);
    }


    public static ArrayList<Dictionary> returnDictionaryWithDistinctDefinition(ArrayList<Dictionary> dictList) {
        HashMap<String, Dictionary> hMap = new HashMap<String, Dictionary>();
        if (dictList != null) {
            for (Dictionary dict : dictList) {
                String definition = dict.definition();
                if (!hMap.containsKey(definition)) {
                    hMap.put(definition, dict);
                }
            }


        }
        return new ArrayList<Dictionary>(hMap.values());
    }
}
```

*The user can type in up to two arguments.
The first argument would be just 'Distinct' and the Dictionary would display all the definitions of distinct stored as Enums.
The second argument can be 'Distinct', which would display all the UNIQUE definitions.*

**So while my program does function as intended, why doesn't my output in photo #1 match up with the output shown in photo #2? (It went out of order) And how can this be fixed?**

*Photo #1 (My Output)*
[image]

*Photo #2 (The required output)*
[image]

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap does not maintain insertion order. Please try using LinkedHashMap. LinkedHashMap maintains insertion order, and you will not see this issue.